# Perform one simulation step

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello everyone!

I'm want to interface ROS and Gazebo to perform a robot control task.

However, I want to have full control of the simulation evolution, by arbitrating the simulation steps.
To be more specific, I publish a simulation clock in ROS and then:
I want to tell Gazebo to execute the next simulation step, gather data, perform calculations over them and publish control outputs for the next simulation steps.
Afterwards, run the next simulation step and start over.

I found [this](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5185/how-to-synchronise-ros-and-gazebo/) question, but it is outdated and with broken links.

Is there anything more recent on this topic?

Thanks,
George

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12138/perform-one-simulation-step/) by [Georacer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2336/georacer/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 37 on 2015-12-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi there,

as @scpeters mentioned in the other question you could publish gazebo [world_control](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/5299916de5cce4a5f3baf8acf75cf6bff68f8184/gazebo/msgs/world_control.proto?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) messages on the `~/world_control` topic. You start the simulation paused and you send a message with `step = true` to step once in the simulation.

Cheers,
Andrei

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2015-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0